# cotangent complex for finite flat morphism and different ideal

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, deformation-theory, singularity-theory

Let a ring $A$, $F=A[X_{1},\dots X_{n}]$ and  $B:= F/J$.

We suppose that we have a finite flat lci morphism $f:Spec(B)\rightarrow Spec(A)$.

To mesure the singularities of this map, Gabber-Ramero define an ideal :

$H_{B/A}=Ann_{F}Ext_{B}^{1}(L_{B/A},J/J^{2})$

http://www.math.huji.ac.il/~temkin/papers/Non_Embedded_Desingularization.pdf 3.2.2,

we also have the different ideal $\delta_{B/A}$ which is the suppport of the module $\Omega_{B/A}^{1}$.

How can we compare both?